# Adding a discount code to paypal button

Tags: javascript, paypal, discount, paypal-buttons

I'm trying to add a discount code to the paypal button, The javascript works and says the discount code is valid but isn't taking the discount off the amount when you click the buy now button to pay.

Can anyone help me please

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<p>Please click on the link to pay</p>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo C_OUR_EMAIL; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo strfordisp($ofirstname); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="<?php echo strfordisp($olastname); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="<?php echo strfordisp($theorder["oaddress"]); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="<?php echo strfordisp($theorder["oaddress2"]); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="address3" value="<?php echo strfordisp($theorder["oaddress3"]); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo strfordisp($theorder["otown"]); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php echo strfordisp($theorder["opostcode"]); ?>" />


<?php
$orderdets = mysql_query("select * from c4d_orderitems where orderid='" . $_SESSION["db_order"] . "' and confirm");
$iloop = 1;
while ($orderrow = mysql_fetch_array($orderdets))
{
$itemdesc = $orderrow["itemtypedesc"];
$itemdesc .= " to " . $orderrow["dpostcode"];
$itemprice = $orderrow["cost"] + $orderrow["surcharge"] + $orderrow["insurancecost"];
?>
<input type='hidden' name="item_name_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value='<?php echo strfordisp($itemdesc); ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name="item_number_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value='<?php echo $orderrow["itemtype"]; ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name="amount_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value='<?php
  if ((strtoupper($ofirstname)=="PCTRENDSTEST") || (strtoupper($olastname)=="PCTRENDSTEST") || (substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,11)=="82.152.55.1"))
  echo("0.01");
  else echo $itemprice;
?>' />


<input type='hidden' name="baseamt_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value='<?php if ((strtoupper($ofirstname)=="PCTRENDSTEST") || (strtoupper($olastname)=="PCTRENDSTEST") || (substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,11)=="82.152.55.1"))
  echo("0.01");
  else echo $itemprice;
?>' />
 <input type="hidden" name="basedes_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value="" />



<input type='hidden' name="quantity_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value='1' />

<?
    $iloop++;
  }
  ?>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo C_SITE_ROOT; ?>stage7.php" />
<meta http-equiv="return" content="3;url=stage7.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel-return" value="<?php echo C_SITE_ROOT; ?>order-cancel.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo C_SITE_ROOT; ?>paypal.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["db_order"]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="no-shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="GB" />


Enter Coupon code
<input type="text" size="10" name="coupcode"; />
<input type="button" value="Check code" onclick="coupval =this.form.coupcode.value;  ChkCoup();" />



<p class='fmenu'><input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
     <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></p>
     </form>
```

The javascript is:

```
var discnt = 0;   // no default percent discount



var coupons = new Array (  // place to put coupon codes

  "coup1",                 // 1st coupon value - comma seperated

  "coup2",                 // 2nd coupon value - add all you want

  "coup3"                  // 3rd coupon value
);
var coupdc  = new Array ( 5,10,15
 // place to put discounts for coupon vals
);
var coupval = "(blanket)"; // what user entered as coupon code
function ChkCoup () {      // check user coupon entry
var i;
  discnt = 0;              // assume the worst
  for (i=0; i<coupons.length; i++) {
    if (coupval == coupons[i]) {
      discnt = coupdc[i];  // remember the discount amt
      alert ("This is a valid promo code! \n\n" + discnt + "%" +" discount now in effect.");
      return;

    }
  }
  alert ("'" + coupval + "'  is not a valid promo code!");
}
function Pound (val) {      // force to valid Pound amount
var str,pos,rnd=0;
  if (val < .995) rnd = 1;  // for old Netscape browsers
  str = escape (val*1.0 + 0.005001 + rnd);  // float, round, escape
  pos = str.indexOf (".");
  if (pos > 0) str = str.substring (rnd, pos + 3);
  return str;
}
function ReadForm (obj1) {  // apply the discount
var amt,des;
  amt = obj1.amount_<?php echo $iloop; ?>.value*1.0;       // base amount
  des = obj1.basedes_<?php echo $iloop; ?>.value;           // base description
  if (discnt > 0) {                   // only if discount is active
    amt = Pound (amt - (amt * discnt/100.0));
    des = des + ", " + discnt + "%" + "dis, COUP = " + coupval;
  }
  obj1.amount.value = Pound (amt);
  obj1.item_name.value = des;
}
```

Comment: Is your code ever alerting "This is a valid promo code"? Meaning* It satisfied the if statement?

Comment: Yes the javascript works its just not taking the discount of the price

Comment: I can't seem to find where you're calling ReadForm(). You can call it in ChkCoup. This looks like you have the right idea by passing an object you change the reference which is correct. You can check this by doing an alert in ReadForm() of des. + that value you're passing is a string? Number%dis, COUP = 40?

Comment: A useful site for coupon and discount code scripts is http://ccaples.com/index.php/basic-scripts